# ExtJS - Modifying combobox items

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

I was searching the docs and can't found a consistent and easy way to change a combobox item list. I've used combo.getStore().add(...) and combo.getStore().removeAll() but the widget doesn't update. How can I achieve this?

PS : I have this combobox in a Ext.grid.Panel, using the CellEditing plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the [`queryCaching`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-queryCaching) parameter to `false` (it is `true` by default).

From the docs:

> When true, this prevents the combo from re-querying (either locally or remotely) when the current query is the same as the previous query.
>
> Defaults to: `true`

Comment: I've turned false the parameter, but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: I'm using this: combo.getStore().add({text: "text", value: "value"}); and:combo.getStore().removeAll(). The combo.getStore().data reflects the changes but when I click on the combobox again, the store data is returned to the initial state.(same items, none of the changes remain)